# Finish Circular reveal animation at specific location of view

Tags: java, android, android-animation, circularreveal

I am working with Circular reveal animation. Its working properly.

**This is my code:**

```
int cx = (int) (first_layout.getMeasuredWidth() / 2f);
int cy = (int) (first_layout.getMeasuredHeight() / 2f);

float radius = (float) Math.sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(first_layout, cx, cy, radius, 0);

// make the view invisible when the animation is done
anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

        first_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linear_animation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        final ObjectAnimator logo_left = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(logo_splash, "translationX", Utils.convertDpToPixel((logo_width / 2) * -1, MainSplashActivity.this));
        final ObjectAnimator anim_right = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(logo_text, "translationX", Utils.convertDpToPixel(text_width / 2, MainSplashActivity.this));
        final AnimatorSet animSet_left = new AnimatorSet();
        logo_left.setDuration(500);
        anim_right.setDuration(500);
        animSet_left.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

        animSet_left.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                logo_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                linear_animation.clearAnimation();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainSplashActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
                Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View) logo_splash, "MyImage");
                Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create((View) logo_text, "logoText");

                Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainSplashActivity.this, pair1, pair2).toBundle();

                startActivity(intent, options);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
                }
            });

            animSet_left.playTogether(logo_left, anim_right);
            animSet_left.start();    
        }
    });

anim.setDuration(1500);
anim.start();
```

**Requirement :**

I want to finish circular reveal animation at specific imageview which is in center of my parent layout. As you know that circular reveal finishes with fully centered. But i don't want that.

I want that circular reveal animation should be finished when it will reach the bounds of imageview(which is in center of my parent layout.). I hope all of you will understand my question.

Advanced help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `"I want to finish circular reveal animation at specific imageview"` - so where exactly? in the center of that `ImageView` or in some corner? or somewhere else? post some image depicting your idea

Comment: Yes. Animation should be finished at the edges (bounds) of imageview

Comment: so what is the problem with calculating `endRadius`?

Comment: Its not finishing with the bounds of imageview.

Comment: that use correct `startRadius` and `endRadius` those are two radii used for the animation: `"startRadius float: The starting radius of the animating circle.
endRadius float: The ending radius of the animating circle."`

Comment: Let me check !!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the animation should stop as soon as it reaches the corners of your centered ImageView.

Do the radius calculation (your first 3 lines) for the ImageView as well and pass the resulting radius as last argument in `createCircularReveal`,
which is the end radius. 
However this only works if your ImageView is perfectly centered.